# Angular 6 - using await for http client, how can I get status code if failed

Tags: angular

Suppose I have `let response = await this.http.post(url, list).toPromise()`, is there any way I can get the status code, such as 200, 404 and so on, while still using await. Thanks

Comment: You should use custom request (HttpClient.request) instead of post to get response codes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to use a `try` and `catch` block for that. You'll get the error in the `catch` block.

The `catch` block will get an instance of type `HttpErrorResponse` which has a `status` property on it.

Something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  async ngOnInit () {
    try {
      const response = await this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/13').toPromise();
      console.log(response);
    } catch(error) {
      console.log('Error Status: ', error.status);
    }
  }

}
```

### UPDATE:

Since you're using `HttpClient` and not `observe`ing the `'response'`, you'll only get the response payload data in the response that you get. If you want the `status` as well for it, you'll have to paas an httpOption `{ observe: 'response' }`. Something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  async ngOnInit () {
    try {
      const response = await this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1', { observe: 'response' }).toPromise();
      console.log('Response Status: ', response.status);
      console.log('Response Body: ', response.body);
    } catch(error) {
      console.log('Error Status: ', error.status);
    }
  }

}
```

> Here's an Updated [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-async-await-error-response?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Thanks SiddAjmera, it looks great. There is one more question. How can I distinguish from 200 and 201? Thanks. I tried to get response.status, but got undefined. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Ben, since you're using `HttpClient` and not `observe`ing the `response`, you'll only get the response payload data in the `response` that you get. If you want the status as well for it, you'll have to paas an `httpOption` `{ observe: 'response' }`. Let me update the answer for you.

Comment: Thanks, @SiddAjmera, your answer helps a lot.

Comment: Even if my code is exactly the same, error.status in catch returns 0. While in Network tab the API returns 413. Why that might be? Note that I am also getting CORS error even if Access-Control-Allow-Origin header allows it.

Comment: That completely depends on the API. Could you please reproduce this over a sample stackblitz and share it across?